# JSON schema for FastAPI request body

Tags: fastapi

Is there a way to specify a JSON schema (ie not pydantic models) for the request body and use the automated documentation features (ie to have "Try it out" with support for that schema) ?

Comment: You could create an array of fields you expect in the body, and compare the keys present in `req.json()` with that for validation, and extend Swagger for the "try it out" support, but why not use pydantic which achieves exactly that?

Comment: I also want to do this. The use case is that I have a complex json schema which is language independent. So I want to use that schema with FastAPI to avoid duplication. @roshnet does your comment mean that it is not possible?

Comment: @mauvilsa Sorry I could not understand what you mean by duplication with FastAPI, could you please elaborate? A quick search gives me https://pypi.org/project/json-schema-matcher which can compare two schemas if you're looking to do that.

Comment: I don't want to compare schemas. Your comment said to use a pydantic model but I don't want to write a pydantic model from scratch, since I already have a jsonschema. I am new to pydantic, but https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/ would achieve what I want. Though it is not ideal. Would be much better if I could do something like `model = pydantic.model_from_schema(schema)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by building a rapidoc based web page, that consumes the JSON (or YAML) openapi specification and generates the HTML contents on the client side.